# Make frames in Emacs GUI behaves like frames in Terminal

Tags: emacs

In terminal, Emacs manage multiple frames with names like F1, F2.... because it can't create multiple OS windows. I want the GUI version to behave this way, that is, instead of creating multiple OS windows, I want it to create many virtual frames inside a single Emacs window. Is there a way?

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Non_002dWindow-Terminals.html#Non_002dWindow-Terminals

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is that you want to be able to access frames by name, then yes, you can do this with [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

By default, `C-x 5 o` is bound to [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands#multi-command) `icicle-select-frame`.  This lets you select one or more frames by name.

A frame's name comes from its `name` frame parameter.  It is suffixed as needed by `[NUMBER]`, to
make it unique.  For example, in a context where frames are named for
their buffers and you have two frames showing buffer `*Help*`, one of
the frames will be called `*Help*[2]` for use with this command.

Frame selection with `C-x 5 o` uses completion and cycling.  The completion can be vanilla Emacs completion or regexp (including, of course, substring) completion.  (It can also be any of several fuzzy completions.)

(If, for some reason, you want the frame names to be just `F1`, `F2`, etc., as with terminal Emacs, then you just need to do that at the level of frame parameter `name`.  You can do that using hooks etc.)

Comment: I'm thinking the question is more about the `screen`-like functionality of being able to switch between virtual frames. I have wished for that, too.

Comment: I imagine something like that could be done via `save-window-configuration` and its sibling functions, but not in a place where I can experiment.

Comment: @triplee Virtual frames?  Sorry, but your comments are not clear to me. And I don't see anything in the question that relates to `save-window-configuration`.

Comment: With `emacs -nw`, `C-x 5 2` creates what looks like a fresh Emacs session, and you can switch back to what you were doing before with `C-x 5 o`. It's neat, try it!

Comment: @triplee: No, it's nothing like a fresh Emacs session. `C-x 5 2` does the same thing that it always does: make a new frame. And `C-x 5 o` does what it always does: select another frame. The OP question, as I understand it, is how to **choose a frame by name** (e.g. instead of just cycling via `other-frame`), when using GUI Emacs.  (It may also include how to name frames `F1` etc.)

Comment: @Drew Well i'm sorry for being ambiguous, but tripleee is correct. I want Emacs to create frames similar to how terminal handles it. I will update my question.

Comment: There are no "frames" in `emacs -nw`, obviously. This feature was introduced in v23, I think; older Emacsen would just beep if you tried to use frame commands without a GUI.

Comment: @triplee: I am assuming that the OP is using Emacs 22 or later. And for that, yes, there **are** frames in `emacs -nw`. See `(emacs) Non-Window Terminals`. They are not window-manager windows.  But they are Emacs frames.

Comment: Fine. So can we make GUI frames behave like these non-GUI frames?

Comment: With the new information that you (Amumu) want not only to select a frame by name in GUI Emacs but to change the nature of its frames to simulate the frames of terminal Emacs, my answer does not answer the question; sorry. (My question in that case would by why you want to use GUI Emacs if you want it, in effect, confined to a terminal window. Why not just use `emacs -nw`?)

Comment: Drew: I'm not sure that switching to a terminal is a helpful suggestion. Clearly Amumu is already aware of running Emacs in a terminal, and would presumably be doing that already if it was sufficient. Personally I think the key modifier limitations of most terminals is reason enough to want GUI Emacs, but there are also many graphical and font niceties which can make GUI Emacs more agreeable.

Comment: @phils: I didn't mean to *suggest* that Amumu switch to a terminal. I meant only to say that I don't quite understand *why* s?he wants GUI with terminal-like frames (not just selecting a frame by name, which is what I originally thought the question was about). I'm with you wrt preferring GUI Emacs for multiple reasons. Certainly there are multiple advantages (keys, fonts etc.). I just wondered out loud about the reason for the preferred combination.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to mimic the frame switching behavior of terminal emacs in GUI. Here is what I did. Basicly it uses `make-frame-invisible` to hide inactive frames. It works well on archlinux with i3.

```
(defsubst +amos--is-frame-daemons-frame (f)
(and (daemonp) (eq f terminal-frame)))

(defun +amos--frame-list-without-daemon ()
"Return a list of frames without the daemon's frame."
(if (daemonp)
    (filtered-frame-list
    #'(lambda (f) (not (+amos--is-frame-daemons-frame f))))
    (frame-list)))

(defun +amos/workspace-new ()
(interactive)
(let ((name (frame-parameter nil 'name))
        (oframe (selected-frame)))
    (select-frame (if (s-starts-with? "F" name)
                    (make-frame)
                    (make-frame `((name . ,name)))))
    (make-frame-invisible oframe t))
(setq +amos--frame-list (reverse (+amos--frame-list-without-daemon))))

(setq +amos-tmux-need-switch nil)

;; TODO ring lru
(defun +amos/workspace-delete ()
(interactive)
(let ((f (selected-frame)))
    (select-frame (previous-frame))
    (make-frame-visible)
    (delete-frame f))
(setq +amos--frame-list (reverse (+amos--frame-list-without-daemon)))
(+doom-modeline|set-selected-window)
(realign-windows)
(when +amos-tmux-need-switch
    (shell-command! "tmux switch-client -t amos\; run-shell -t amos '/home/amos/scripts/setcursor.sh $(tmux display -p \"#{pane_tty}\")'")
    (setq +amos-tmux-need-switch nil)))

(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to (index)
(interactive)
(when (< index (length +amos--frame-list))
    (let ((frame (nth index +amos--frame-list))
        (oframe (selected-frame)))
    (select-frame frame)
    (raise-frame frame)
    (make-frame-invisible oframe t)
    (setq +amos-tmux-need-switch nil)
    (realign-windows)
    (recenter))))

(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-1 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 0))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-2 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 1))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-3 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 2))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-4 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 3))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-5 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 4))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-6 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 5))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-7 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 6))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-8 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 7))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-to-9 () (interactive) (+amos/workspace-switch-to 8))
(defun +amos-workspace-cycle (off)
(let* ((n (length +amos--frame-list))
        (index (-elem-index (selected-frame) +amos--frame-list))
        (i (% (+ off index n) n)))
    (+amos/workspace-switch-to i)))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-left ()  (interactive) (+amos-workspace-cycle -1))
(defun +amos/workspace-switch-right () (interactive) (+amos-workspace-cycle +1))

(defun +amos|maybe-delete-frame-buffer (frame)
(let ((windows (window-list frame)))
    (dolist (window windows)
    (let ((buffer (window-buffer (car windows))))
        (when (eq 1 (length (get-buffer-window-list buffer nil t)))
        (kill-buffer buffer))))))
(add-to-list 'delete-frame-functions #'+amos|maybe-delete-frame-buffer)
```